# Is it possible to get real-time update on conversations?

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

Is it possible to get notification when a user sends private message to someone or receives it from someone?

Comment: @Renan If I had found it I wouldn't have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn't possible without polling the thread id. You can see the list of available connections at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/